# C++ : lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Tags: c++

The following Piece of code worked in my work system, the same code is throwing an error in my PC.

```
std::bitset<32> my_bit(*(uint32_t*)&(OFDM_cod[V][a/8].real()));

Error:
lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Any suggestions why is this happening? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: It would be better to memcopy into a new variable instead of casting anyway. Accessing memory through a pointer of an unrelated type other than char is UB.

Comment: What do you think you are trying to write?  How is declared OFDM_cod, what is the result type of the `.real()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take an address of the temporary, and this is what

```
&(OFDM_cod[V][a/8].real()));
```

is doing. It can be simplified to

```
&x.real(); //here assuming real() does not return a reference
```

and this is not good. Your code probably works in a non-standard compliant compiler, which is relaxed about this stuff - but this behavior is against the C++ standard.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternate way of accessing the value?

Comment: @Harsha, I do not know why you need the address and the cast.

Comment: @Harsha assign to an lvalue (named variable) first. But it is not clear why you need a pointer at all.

Comment: @Slava Assigning OFDM_cod[V][a/8] to another variable gives me the same error.

Comment: @SergeyA is there any other method of casting?? Thank you!

Comment: @Harsha you need to assign `OFDM_cod[V][a/8].real()` to another variable. And looks like you can cast without pointer at all.

Comment: @Slava Thank you very much.It worked. Removed the pointer and assigned to a variable.